# ZF2 application - Dispatch error event triggered every time

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'am working on a Zend Framework 2 application and have a strange behavior concerning error handling. My code in Module.php:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    $eventManager->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, [$this, 'onPreRoute'], 100);
    $eventManager->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, [$this, 'handleError']);
}

public function onPreRoute(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $serviceManager = $e->getTarget()->getServiceManager();
    $router = $serviceManager->get('router');
    $router->setTranslator($serviceManager->get('translator'));
}

public function handleError(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $error = $e->getParam('error');

    file_put_contents('error.log', $error . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

    switch($error) {
        case 'error-router-no-match':
            $router = $e->getRouter();
            $url = $router->assemble([], ['name' => 'home']);
            header('Location: ' . $url);
            exit;
    }
}
```

As you can see I'am translating the routes. This works fine. But on every request the dispatch error event is triggered too. The error.log file will be created every time. But the redirect will be only performed if the route doesn't really exist. I think it depends on the translator or is my code in Module.php not correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved!**

The reason was that the browser automatically requests /favicon.ico and that was not available :-)